# Evaluate user defined math function

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath

I want to "plot" a simple line function, like `f(x) = 3x+5`. Actually, this is perfectly working:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \plot{3*x+5};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But, for line function, I wanted to be able to create a custom command that would take the function as a parameter and evaluate two points on this line. Something like this:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand\myline{m}{
    \draw (-5;\fx{#1}(-5)>) -- (5; \fx{#1}(7)>);
}
\NewDocumentCommand\fx{m r()}{
% this is where I'm missing what to do:
% #1 is the function: #1 = 3*x+5
% #2 is the value to use: x = #2
}
```

where

- `<#1(-5)>` should parse and evaluate the line function at `x=-5`
- `<#1(7)>` should parse and evaluate the line function at `x=7`

Notice that I want to keep the "plot" style function: `3*x+5` and I don't want to have to add a backslash to the `x` like this: `3*\x+5`

I tried to use various `pgfmath` functions, but I must be missing something to make it work :(

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Take a look at this recent post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614848/latex-minimalistic-graphs. Both answers use Ti*k*Z declared functions.

Comment: @JuanCastaño I'm aware of the `declare function`, but then, you need to write the function using `\x`, which I don't want. What I really would like to do is to declare a function that would allow me to simply write `fx{3*x-5}(7)` and would return 16.

Comment: Like: replace x with 7, then integer evaluate? (using expl3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a fully expandable function that allows you to evaluate a function using just `x`. Caveat: Every `x` is replaced with the value, even if you don't want it to be, so you couldn't use the `exp()` function of `l3fp` anymore with this. You can change the variable name which is replaced by using the optional argument, so `\fx[x_1]{exp(x_1/5)}{2}` would work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etl}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \fx { O{x} m m }
  {
    \fp_eval:n { \etl_replace_all_deep:nnn {#2} {#1} {#3} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\fx{3*x+5}{-5} and \fx{3*x+5}{7}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's perfect ! I just changed the function to: `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \fx { O{x} m r() }` so I can write the function more naturally: `\fx{3*x+5}(-5)`

Comment: @BasilGass this might be more natural to you, and `xparse`/`ltcmd` has no issues with it, but please bear in mind that you should follow standard LaTeX rules for argument types where possible. Those are: Required arguments should be in braces. The required arguments in parenthesis are there to support old stuff in LaTeX, like the coordinate arguments in `picture` mode. For this you should really use standard arguments (less so if it's your own file, more so if you share this with others). That's why I used `m` instead, even though your MWE showed `r()`.